# a<b<c $\implies$ |b|$\leqslant$max(|a|,|c|)?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Given **a, b, c** 3 real numbers. Prove that if a < b < c, then |b|$\leqslant$max (|a|,|c|).

I orginally proved this by discussing four cases as

1) a,b,c<0

2) a<0, b,c>0

3) a,b<0, c>0

4) a,b,c>0

Here I wonder if there is an easier way to do this without dividing it into four cases and discussing them separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some casework is unavoidable; what you have is fine.

If $b=0$, the inequality is clear. If $b\ne 0$, then at least one of $a$ and $c$ has the same sign as $b$ and is farther away from zero. [Explicitly, if $b>0$, then $c>b>0 \implies |b| <|c|$; if $b<0$, then $a<b<0 \implies |b| <|a|$.]

Comment: trivial comment: how do you do double-lined right arrow

Comment: It is `\implies`. Some people use `\Rightarrow`.
You can view the source code by right-clicking and clicking "show math as TeX commands," or alternatively, clicking "edit" to edit the post.

Comment: Thanks! Another comment: |b|<|C| or |b|<|a| will not guarantee |b|<max(|a|,|c|), take -3<2<3 or -2<-1<3, where gets really tedious: you need to divide the case by two cases again: |a|<|c| or |a|>|c|, and that is what I am trying to avoid

Comment: @QiminLiu But $|c| \le \max(|a|,|c|)$ and $|a| \le \max(|a|,|c|)$ no matter what $a$ and $c$ are.

Comment: @QiminLiu If you have $b>0$, then $|b|<|c|$, which implies $$|b|<|c| \le \max(|a|,|c|).$$

Comment: You are right! I was overcomplicating on this! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

It's always true that $b<c$ and $-b<-a$. Just use the first inequality if $b\ge 0$ and the second when $b<0$:
$$
b \ge 0 \Rightarrow |b|<|c|<\max\left(|a|,|c|\right)\\
b < 0 \Rightarrow |b|<|a|<\max\left(|a|,|c|\right)
$$

Comment: Great answer, thanks!